# Session handling in Django Python with Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, session, web-frameworks

I am currently using Google App Engine to host my Django applications. I want to implement sessions in my Django application. I cannot use the default session handling of Django because it is not supported in Google App Engine.

After some research (basically Googling), I found that [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) is the recommended library. I tried to do wrap my head around the demo provided in the library but I could not understand how it works. Please help me in writing code which will set and maintain session variables for a user. I am also open to using any other library with better documentation for session handling, so kindly point me towards one, if you know.

Comment: What's to understand? The page you link to has instructions on configuring with Django. Exactly where are you having trouble?

Comment: Hi Daniel. I am not able to get how to set sessions and session variables. Also, do you think it is a good library? Or there are others which I can look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) is quite easy to use. You can set it up following the instructions provided on the github page. I will elaborate on the usage through an example of implementing login page.

Suppose that in your `views.py` you define a function as follows:

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),label = "Password")

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entered_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            entered_pass = form.cleaned_data['password']
            try:
                _user = user.objects.get(email=entered_email)
                stored_password = _user.password
                if stored_password == entered_pass:
                    session = get_current_session()
                    if session.is_active():
                        session.terminate()
                    session['email'] = entered_email
                    return  'REDIRECT AS REQUIRED'
                else:
                    print "INCORRECT PASSWORD"
                    form = loginForm()
                    return render(request, 'login.html',{ 'form': form })
            except:
                print "EMAIL NOT REGISTERED"
                form = loginForm()
                return render(request, 'login.html',{ 'form': form })
    else:
        form = loginForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html',{ 'form': form })
```

In the above code, `loginForm` is used to define the input fields where the user will enter the credentials which he/she can use to login into the system. The `login` method is used to check the entered credentials against the database and if found to be valid a session is set using `gae-sessions`. You will need to place the following import in your `views.py`

```
from gaesessions import get_current_session
```

In the `login` method presented above, we access the session using `get_current_session()` method which is imported from gae-sessions. Values for the session can be set according to your requirements. I have set `session['email']` value for maintaining the session. The session can be terminated using simple `session.terminate()`.

Be sure to follow the installation instructions provided [here](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions#installation). I hope you find this useful!